# Appium AndroidDriver.getCurrentPackage() equivalent in IOSDriver

Tags: java, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I'm doing an UI automation on mobile using Appium and need a API to check what app is running on top.

For android I have found that the `driver.getCurrentPackage()` return the package name of the app. But couldn't find a similar one for the IOS driver.

```
loginPage.login(email,password);
if(!driver.getCurrentPackage().equals("my.app.package") {
    throw RuntimeException("App crashed");
}
```

The above code works fine for the android mobiles, but need a way to make this work even for IOS mobiles.